# Determine whether pymongo/documentdb has successfully inserted before moving on or trying another query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I am using pymongo on an AWS DocumentDB backend. I am trying to create a system where a user can post a query, and then use that query soon after posting. Something like:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
client.db.queries.insert_one({'key': 'myKey', 'query': {'filter': 'test'}})
---
query = client.db.queries.find_one({'key': 'myKey'})
client.db.elements.find(query['query'])
```

This works most of the time, but sometimes the `find_one` on the third line will fail, returning no documents. I was having trouble understanding the documentation around how DocumentDB/Pymongo blocks for inserts, so I put together a little experiment:

```py
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()

print('prev: ', len(list(client.test.collection.find())))   # 0
print(client.test.collection.insert_one({'test': 'test'}))  # <pymongo.results.InsertOneResult object at 0x7f010806a0c0>
print('after: ', len(list(client.test.collection.find())))  # 0 -- I would expect this to be 1 if the insert succeeded
```

and I found that the insert was non-blocking.

Another example:

```py
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()

print('prev: ', len(list(client.test.collection.find())))   # 0
insert_result = client.test.collection.insert_one({'test': 'test'}))
print('inserted?', list(client.test.collection.find({'_id': insert_result.inserted_id})))  # [] -- I would expect this to have the inserted doc
print('after: ', len(list(client.test.collection.find())))  # 0 -- I would expect this to be 1 if the insert succeeded
```

Eventually, if I put a sleep or enough code between the insert and the finds, I will get results. So the insert is *succeeding*, just not immediately.

How am I supposed to determine whether a write has actually completed? I don't want to run another query unless I am sure the previous inserts have finished -- is there a way to make pymongo respect the insert order before running find queries?

Comment: The [InsertOneResult](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertOneResult) has the information which you can check if the insert is successful or not. Also, you can have a `try-catch` block enclosing the insert statement, and in case there is an error you will know for sure there was a problem.

Comment: @prasad_ thanks for the response. Checking the InsertOneResult is not helpful -- it returns acknowledge and the id, but the find count still remains unchanged. Similarly, the try-catch does not change the success of the find.

Comment: Try this: `insertResult = client.test.collection.insert_one({'test': 'test'})`.

Comment: Yep, already tried that. I can see that the insertResult is acknowledged and I can access the inserted_id. However, the find() still does not trigger. See my edit in the above for an example. The insert is not _failing_, it just doesn't complete immediately or block.

Comment: The correct way to count the documents would be to use the `collection.count_documents()` method (pls check the PyMongo syntax). Assign the returned count into a variable and then print the count.

Comment: The count is not actually helpful, it is just illustrative of my problem. I am not trying to actually count how many documents there are, rather I am trying to find a document that has recently been inserted. Even if the count_documents() returns the correct count, if the find() does not it is not helpful.

Comment: Are you using a read preference of `Secondary`?  Can you please provide your connection string (scrubbed of passwords, of course)...

Comment: Here's the connection string:

```client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@dev.cluster.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false' % (user, quote(password)))```

It does in fact look like the readPref is secondaryPreferred. What does that entail/mean?

Comment: maybe mongodb transactions might be helpful here

Answer (score 1):

Change read preference to `primary` or `primaryPreferred`. Please get familiar with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/how-it-works.html#durability-consistency-isolation to understand trade-offs. This part in particular:

> Supported Read Preference Options
>
> **primary**—Specifying a primary read preference helps ensure that all reads are routed to the cluster’s primary instance. If the primary instance is unavailable, the read operation fails. A primary read preference yields read-after-write consistency and is appropriate for use cases that prioritize read-after-write consistency over high availability and read scaling.
>
> The following example specifies a primary read preference:
>
> ```
> db.example.find().readPref('primary')
> ```
>
> **primaryPreferred**—Specifying a primaryPreferred read preference routes reads to the primary instance under normal operation. If there is a primary failover, the client routes requests to a replica. A primaryPreferred read preference yields read-after-write consistency during normal operation, and eventually consistent reads during a failover event. A primaryPreferred read preference is appropriate for use cases that prioritize read-after-write consistency over read scaling, but still require high availability.
>
> The following example specifies a primaryPreferred read preference:
>
> ```
> db.example.find().readPref('primaryPreferred')
> ```